# how to show data in labels in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, label, data-layer

I have two layers, a data layer which gets the results from the database and a UI layer which will show the data in label controls
 Here is the code of data layer

```
public class Test_DAL
{
    public DataSet getEMP(string name1)
    {

        string conn = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Connect.txt");
        //string conn="Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=pss;Integrated Security=True";
        //string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
        SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        dbconn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from pss where Emp_code='"+name1+"'", dbconn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dbconn.Close();
        return ds;
    }

}
```

And it is the code of the UI layer

```
    private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string empcode=txt_empcode.Text;
        Test_DAL obj1= new Test_DAL();
        obj1.getEMP(empcode);
        //dg.DataSource = obj1.getEMP(empcode).Tables[0];


    }
```

And my question is how to show data on labels

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is not very clear. Just to give you an idea of how you can do is

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string empcode=txt_empcode.Text;
        Test_DAL obj1= new Test_DAL();
        DataSet ds = obj1.getEMP(empcode);
        //displays the data of row 1 column 1 of table 1
        yourLabel.Text  = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(); 


    }
```

Note: This is neither the best not the appropriate way of doing things. There isn't any exception handling etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would make `GetEmployee` return an actual `Employee` type.

```
public Employee getEMP(string name1)
{
    // left out some of your code intentionally
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from pss where Emp_code='"+name1+"'", dbconn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dbconn.Close();
    return new Employee(ds);
}
```

And define a class `Employee` that would look like

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* Other properties ... */ 

    public Employee(DataSet dataset)
    {
        Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        // etc
    }
}
```

That way your UI layer can talk to actual objects (entities), instead of having to bother with magic numbers in `DataSet`s, and for example rely on data binding in your UI.

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string empcode=txt_empcode.Text;
    Test_DAL obj1= new Test_DAL();

    var employee = obj1.getEMP(empcode);

    dg.DataSource = employee;
}
```